# kafka Manager not showing consumer lag or Sum of partition offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I don't know if it is config issue or not. The kafka manager can get everything except consumer lag. Can anyone help me?

I'm using kafka 2.2.0[image]

I also checked logs, no errors at all.

And also one of the important thing is that my code base is processing messages and inserting it to database as well.
But why I posted this question is because I may not be to see lags in the topic if it exist or not.
So that I can decide how many consumer i have to run.